# How to change picture in ImageView every second using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I would like to have ImageView change picture every 1 second. I've tried using Java-specific solutions using Handler but weren't able to translate them correctly.

Basically, I have a list of image resources:

```kotlin
    val loopImages = listOf(R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four)
```

and I want to change the pictures in a loop every 1 second. That was my current attempt that didn't work:

```kotlin
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = Runnable() {
    var i = 0

    fun run() {
        binding.slideImage.setImageResource(loopImages[i])
        i++
        if (i > loopImages.size - 1) {
            i = 0
        }
        handler.postDelayed({ run() }, 2000)
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)
```

Is there any way to do it completely in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun startSlider() {
    Handler().apply {
        val runnable = object : Runnable {
            var index = 0
            var imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
            override fun run() {
                imageView.setImageResource(loopImages[index])
                index++
                if (index > loopImages.size - 1) {
                    index = 0
                }
                postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        }
        postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to do it completely in Kotlin?

Not really sure what you mean by this - your code is written in Kotlin syntax.

You can achieve a similar result using coroutines which removes the requirement for runnables and handlers, if that is closer to what you meant.

Untested code but something like this should work :

```
private fun imageChanger(scope: CoroutineScope, images: List<Int>, target: ImageView, periodMillis : Long = 2_000): Job =
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
            if (images.isNotEmpty()) {
                var idx = 0
                while (isActive) {
                    if(idx >= images.size) idx = 0
                    images[idx].let(target::setImageResource)
                    idx++
                    delay(periodMillis)
                }
            }
        }
```

Its a bit scrappy but can be refined.